# Reading large data from mongoDB in batches - Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo, large-data

I have 75 million records in my `MongoDB`. I need to read the whole data in batches (of say 100,000), store it in some sort of stream / queue. Once the stream has data, a Python script will read from it and operate upon the data.

Basically I want the results of `collection.find()` to be served in batches of 100,000.

I know I can do `collection.find()[0:100000]` and then `collection.find()[100000:200000]` and so on as seen - [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.__getitem__)

But I'm worried about the efficiency of running 'skip' every time.

I'm aware of `cursor.batchSize()` but I'm not sure how to use that to sequentially keep reading data.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Use `$gt` from the "Last Seen" `_id` value on the collection, presuming you are basically reading in that order. Otherwise it would be a similar "range" selection by whatever the sort order is, "plus" a `$nin` for excluding some of the "last seen ids" from the previous page if the "sorted" values are not unique.

Comment: I encountered similar problem and I founded this solution, may be if this can help: 
 
https://gist.github.com/ccca495816e5d5102e50a0429664ce34.git